# Heroku Toolbelt fails to detect a set buildpack

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, buildpack

I have tried manually [clearing and setting the buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#setting-a-buildpack-on-an-application) for my Rails app to heroku/rails. I have verified that I have a Gemfile, and I still get this error

```
    remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/ruby
    remote:
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to detect set buildpack heroku/ruby
    remote: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
    remote:
    remote: Verifying deploy...
    remote:
    remote: !   Push rejected
```

Which is confusing since I set the buildpack but then it can't detect it.  Some of my routes are rendering json as I wanted this app to serve as a backend API. Do I need to add a buildpack for Node? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the app located within a redundant subfolder in the git repo. I fixed the problem by moving everything up a level, recommitting, and `git push heroku master`. Heroku was looking for a Gemfile in the top level, so I moved all the application files to the top level (where it should have been all along).

Answer (score 0):

I reinitialized the repo and did it again. Did my commits and pushed. Worked!!!

```
git init
```

add heroku as a remote

```
git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/appname.git'
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push heroku master
```